# Flutter How to pass data from one screen to another if I need it before the BuildContext?

Tags: flutter, widget, parameter-passing

I want to send a request with a specific id but I can only get the id after I receive it from previous screen in the build widget

```
void gettingTime() async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.11/Backend/dateValide.php?id=$id'),);
    print("StatusCodeDetail== ${response.statusCode}");
    if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
      setState(() {
        dataListTime = json.decode(response.body); //we store the json data in a list
        print("RESPONSE${response.body}");
      });

    }
    else {
      print("Error in loading from the server");

    }
     }
  

    @override
  

    void initState() {
        gettingTime();
        super.initState();
      }
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        dataMap=ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map;//We recieve the data as a Map from the home screen
        String id=dataMap["previousScreenData"]["ID_EXCURSION"];
```

Comment: I sense a question coming. :) You did not ask a question and what exactly is your problem that you are looking to resolve?

Comment: Did you mean? widget.yourParameter

Answer (score 0):

[Pass the id as an argument](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments) for the widget's constructor using the router

Edit: You didn't really ask a question, so I answered: "How can I pass data from one screen to another if I need it before the BuildContext is known?" Hope it helps :-)